# add two numbers represented by linked lists using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

PS: There are multiple posts on add two numbers represented by linked lists  but none talks about recursive solution. So please do not mark as duplicate of downvote.

> Q. You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two
>   non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each
>   of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return
>   it as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.

My attempt

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(0);
        recursiveAdd(l1, l2, l3, 0);
        return l3;
    }

    private void recursiveAdd(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, ListNode l3, int carryOver){
        if(l1 != null || l2!= null){
            l3.val = (l1==null?0:l1.val + (l2==null?0:l2.val) + carryOver)%10;
            l3.next = new ListNode(0);
            int carryOverNew = (l1==null?0:l1.val + (l2==null?0:l2.val) + carryOver)/10;
            recursiveAdd(l1.next, l2.next, l3.next, carryOverNew);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:
Given I am creating new node everytime, after termination there is always a extra node with value 0. How to get rid of this?
Example:

> Your input [2,4,3] [5,6,4]
>
> Output [7,0,8,0]
>
> Expected [7,0,8]

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far. Have you debugged the code? What have you noticed when debugging? What was not clear when debugging?

Comment: Already shared. It is just that I am initializing new node and even if the recursion terminates that new node results in extra 0 at end always.

Comment: Don't create a node with 0. Create a node with a desired value only when you need it.

Comment: how ? not able to think how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You create another node in the result list before checking if you really need it. Here's how to solve that issue:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(0);
        recursiveAdd(l1, l2, l3, 0);
        return l3;
    }

    private void recursiveAdd(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, ListNode l3, int carryOver){
        //calculate value of the current digit
        l3.val = ((l1 == null ? 0 : l1.val) + (l2 == null ? 0 : l2.val) + carryOver) % 10;

        //calculate carry over to the next digit
        int carryOverNew = ((l1 == null ? 0 : l1.val) + (l2 == null ? 0 : l2.val) + carryOver) / 10;

        //take the next digit from the two operands
        if (l1 != null) l1 = l1.next;
        if (l2 != null) l2 = l2.next;

        //another digit is only needed if at least one these are true:
        //1. the first operand has another digit
        //2. the second operand has another digit
        //3. the carry over is more than zero
        if (l1 != null || l2 != null || carryOverNew > 0) {
            //only create another digit when it is needed
            l3.next = new ListNode(0);
            recursiveAdd(l1, l2, l3.next, carryOverNew);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution has been tested with the example input and two zeros ([0] and [0] adding correctly to [0]).

**Edit:** I've added null checks before taking the next element of l1 and l2 to prevent NullPointerExceptions, and added parentheses around the first ternary operator (?:) in the calculation of l3.val and carryOverNew to prevent false results.

Comment: This is better than the OP. Now think if you really need parameter *l3* and if you could eliminate it :)

Comment: This won't work. If list has just one node. I guess needs another layer of checks when doing l1 = l1.next